# How can I add custom Current Location button in Google Place Autocomplete Picker View using cocoa pods below search bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, google-places-api

I have used google guide to integrate Google Place autocomplete api in my app using [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) link through cocoa pods.Now I want to add my custom button to set my current location automatically any time when I want to, by clicking on the location button but as I have integrated using cocoa pods it not allow me to set my button on google view. 
I want same look and feel as shown in image [image: screenshot]
I appreciate if anyone help to know how to add custom button using SDK or cocoa pods.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any way to add custom cell or button inside Google Autocomplete . But you can do this to add `tableView` under the `UISearchBar` as shown below the image[image]

And Follow the link [on IOS, Looking for option to detect current location in google place sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711207/on-ios-looking-for-option-to-detect-current-location-in-google-place-sdk)

Comment: I had already do the same [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3Euc12tElWSlNISHl3X0pOUUk/view) 
with my custom layout but I just wanted to know if it will be done in google places view or not.

Comment: Not possible..You can check   google map, there is also a custom tableview for current location. If it works, you can give a thumbs up :)